# How add MemberInitExpression into Bindings other Lambda MemberInitExpression

Tags: c#, linq, expression, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I have the following classes:

```
class Source {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SourceItem Item { get; set; }
}

class SourceItem {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

class Dest {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DestItem Item { get; set; }
}

class DestItem{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And I built the following lambda expressions:

```
Expression<Func<Source, Dest>> projectionSource = source => new Dest{
    Id = source.Id,
    Name = source.Name
};

Expression<Func<SourceItem, DestItem>> projectionItem = item => new DestItem
{
    Id = item.Id,
    Price = item.Price
};

Expression<Func<Source, SourceItem>> sourceMember = source => source.Item;
Expression<Func<Dest, DestItem>> destMember = dest => dest.Item;
```

How do I add new element bindings to the list of element bindings of the original projection expression using the memberInitExpression expression from the projectionItem lambda expression? Lambda is needed at the output:

```
source => new Dest() // part of projectionSource expression
{
   Id = source.Id,
   Name = source.Name,
   Item = new DestItem() // part of projectionItem expression
   {
      Id = source.Item.Id,
      Price = source.Item.Price
   }
}
```

I couldn't create a MemberAccess from the lambda destMember and projectionItem and add it to the Bindings List projectionSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't add a member to the bindings list, you build a new expression.

With following helper to replace parameters (if you have EF Core 3+ referenced you can use it's [`ReplacingExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.replacingexpressionvisitor?view=efcore-8.0) instead):

```
public static class ExpressionExt
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacingVisitor { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

You can do something like the following:

```
// get the body
var projectionSourceBody = projectionSource.Body as MemberInitExpression;

// get the "nested" Item members to map:
var sourceMemberE = sourceMember.Body as MemberExpression;
var destMemberE = destMember.Body as MemberExpression;

// replace the "nested" projection expression parameter with source.Item
var projectItemE = projectionItem.Body.ReplaceParameter(
    projectionItem.Parameters[0],
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(projectionSource.Parameters[0], sourceMemberE.Member));

// generate the Item = new DestItem {...} member binding for init expression
var assignItem = Expression.Bind(destMemberE.Member, projectItemE);

// rebuild member init expression with new binding list
// using C# 12 collection expressions here
// can use projectionSourceBody.Bindings.Append(assignItem) instead
var newInitE = Expression.MemberInit(
  projectionSourceBody.NewExpression, 
  [.. projectionSourceBody.Bindings, assignItem]); 

// create new lambda
var newProjectionSource = Expression.Lambda<Func<Source, Dest>>(newInitE, projectionSource.Parameters);
newProjectionSource.Compile(); // compile to at least verify we did something compilable
```

Note that possibly it is worth investigating existing mapper libraries which support such stuff out of the box so you don't need to reinvent the wheel. For example popular AutoMapper "understands" "nested" mappings and supports building expressions to be consumed by LINQ providers - see the [Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) doc (search for `ProjectTo` and `CreateProjection` samples).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please suggest an article/blog/book for studying Expressions?

Comment: @student0011001 TBH I have not read much except for the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/). One thing which helped me a lot when I was learning/experimenting with them was the [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) (no association) with it's `Dump` method which allowed to view the generated expression structure (i.e. - write expression with lambda, dump it and try to repro "by hand") + google for concreate cases.

Comment: @student0011001 also arguably expressions in quite a lot of cases can be replaced with [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview)

Comment: I would recommend this extension also [ReadableExpressions.Visualizers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers)